# Вставка текста в textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Можно ли запретить вставлять текст (ctrl+v) в textbox? Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: Хм, наверняка можно, но _зачем_? Вы обязательно хотите заставить юзера набивать все буквы самостоятельно?

Comment: @VladD да, обязательно

Comment: Но зачем? Это выглядит враждебной по отношению к пользователю фичей.

Comment: @VladD этим никто не будет пользоваться  в широких кругах, пишу для знакомых)

Comment: Ну тогда http://stackoverflow.com/a/5190072/276994

Comment: @VladD благодарствую

Comment: @VladD а ПКМ-paste будет при этом работать?

Comment: @andy.37: В обсуждении говорится, что тоже не будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WinForms самый простой способ отключить вырезание, копирование и вставку в текстовое поле - установить для свойства `ShortcutsEnabled`(Указывает, активны ли хоткис, определенные для данного элемента управления) значение `false`.